# Disable casting array on json field when use toArray() laravel

Tags: php, laravel

When using toArray() method on laravel collection, it convert my json field to array.
how to disable $casts when use toArray() method?

Comment: Don't use `toArray()` method.

Comment: is there any other method? i need to convert it to array and keep the field as raw json

Comment: use `toJson()` method

Comment: how can toJson() solve my problem? i need to keep all column to array and keep 1 column inside as raw json

Comment: I think some more explanation of your problem, with examples of what the issue is are needed in the question.

Comment: Give an example, please.